# Generic members with constructor-supplied implementation

Tags: generics, f#

Consider the following:

```
type Foo(bar:'a -> 'a list) =
  member __.Bar = bar
```

I get a warning on the first `'a` in the parameter list saying:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'obj'.

Why do I get this warning?

In this specific example, is it possible to have a member that converts a value of an arbitrary type to a list of such types and have that member supplied through the constructor? (One could for example imagine `Foo` being instantiated with `List.replicate x` for any integer `x` that the user chooses.)

I don't want to make `Foo` itself generic, because I have many such parameters and members.

(The reason I'm trying this is that I want some kind of structure that, among other things, contains user-overridable generic functions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you make `Foo` generic, you don't need to explicitly provide the generic parameters when calling it if they can be inferred:

```
type Foo<'a>(bar:'a -> 'a list) =
    member __.Bar = bar

Foo(fun x -> [x + 1])
```

I'm not sure if that helps you but in general ["Functions lose genericity when passed as values"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42599144/609639).

Comment: Thanks, the link helped. I didn't know about that.