# Creating an F# object with a generic member

Tags: f#

In F#, I have defined an interface with a generic member:

```ml
type MyType =
    abstract MyMember<'a> : 'a -> int
```

I would like to write a function that can create an object that implements this interface:

```ml
module MyType =

    let create f =
        {
            new MyType with
                member __.MyMember(x) = f x
        }
```

This currently fails to compile with the following error message:

```
This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable 'a could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.
```

Is it possible to make this work via inlining and static resolved type parameters (or something similar)? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer - you can't do it. F# doesn't have higher-rank types, which in simpler terms means that functions lose their genericity when passed as values. This is somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42599144/180286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation for the compile error:

Object expressions construct anonymous classes - these are just regular classes, with a compiler generated name. You're essentially creating a closure which captures `f`.

This is how you'd normally implement it:

```
type MyType =
    abstract MyMember<'a> : 'a -> int

type MyNewType (f) =
    interface MyType with
        member _.MyMember x = f x
```

The type's constructor would have a parameter `f` of type `'a -> int`, where `'a` would normally be decided by the first usage of `MyNewType`.

But there's no way to generalize `f` such that it could be captured *as a value* that would satisfy the generic constraint of `MyMember`. Here sufficiently generic means a type of one order above the generic type.